# Database of medically validated SNPs

Tags: human-biology, genomics, database, snp

I'm looking for all possible sources of clinically tested human SNPs. There is a handful of databases that store SNPs (like dbSNP), but I only need those that have validated presence/absence of phenotypic effects with some additional metadata. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any type of disease, or just a subset?

Comment: @mdperry any Mendelian disease will do.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Did you not find the desired information in the GWAS databases that I mentioned below?

Comment: @WYSIWYG I'm struggling to find true negatives. I've already found plenty of true positives though. Thank you for your answer. I'll wait a couple of days before accepting it in case someone else comes up with a valid way to find true negatives.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I think for that you may have to check the original study and get the statistics

Comment: @EliKorvigo - Be wary of the statistics for GWAS studies. Clinically we don't get too excited about them because the cost-effectiveness of doing a study has surpassed the ability for appropriate statistical analysis - the sample sizes are almost always much too small - too much noise to signal - there are several reviews to discuss this, e.g. [http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18464043] (review)

Comment: @VanceAlbaugh Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, at this moment we have a lot of data but we should be careful before making inferences. There have been a lot of discussion about doing the right statistical analyses.

Comment: @VanceAlbaugh exactly. That's the whole point of this question - I can't rely on available bioinformatic GWAS studies to come up with a set of true negative SNPs due to statistical issues. Hence I desperately try to find something that was clinically validated.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - yeah, good luck with that - I don't know of any GWAS studies that have reproduced externally in a statistically sound way and have been published. If someone did that it would be a big deal because the analysis of the data hasn't been perfected. We have similar questions in metabolomics, proteomics, and RNAseq. Too much noise, not enough signal.

Comment: I've added some references to the data I've managed to collect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search by traits (mostly diseases) for genome wide association, in these databases:

- [Gwasdb2](http://jjwanglab.org/gwasdb)
- [Human genome variation Database](https://gwas.biosciencedbc.jp/): it also links to a Copy number Variation (CNV) database.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this post a tiny bit more useful, I must add that there are several additional sources I've found:

- UniProt has an open dataset called `humsavar`
- ClinVar database
- HGMD database
- OMIM
- A [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25552646) with a manually collected database based on recent publications in Nature Genetics.

Different datasets intersect to some extent, but all in all you get over 200k somewhat validated SNPs.